# What rare pokemon cannot be seen by users (marked as cheaters)?

Tags: pokemon-go

According to [Pokemon Go Hub](https://pokemongohub.net/post/breaking-news/new-anti-cheat-measure-deployed-flagged-accounts-dont-see-rare-pokemon/) a server-side security measure was activated over the weekend which now means previously flagged accounts are no longer able to see rare Pokemon spawns in an area.

Apparently, it's a measure to prevents hacks.

What are the "rare spawn" pokemons included in this?

Comment: Correction: it IS a measure to prevent Gps Spoofing

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [Express.co.uk](http://www.express.co.uk/entertainment/gaming/810222/Pokemon-Go-news-Niantic-Pokemon-Go-update-Promo-Codes-Sprint), the following Pokémon cannot be seen by flagged users:

> This includes: Evolved Pokemon, Starters, Caterpie, Weedle, Spearow, Clefairy, Vulpix, Jigglypuff, Venonat, Mankey, Growlithe, Abra, Slowpoke, Gastly, Onix, Drowzee, Voltorb, Koffing, Chansey, Tangela, Horsea, Scyther, Lapras, Eevee, Porygon, Omanyte, Kabuto, Aerodactyl, Snorlax, Dratini, Hoothoot, Chinchou, Mareep, Sudowoodo, Aipom, Unown, Girafarig, Shuckle, Sneasel, Teddiursa, Remoraid, Stantler, Larvitar.

Comment: I thought caterpie was a common pokemon!

Comment: @TheGreatDuck , I agree, but as SE suggests. I am just sharing my research... Additionally, it wasn't specified that _rare_ Pokémon were to be hidden, they just specified _some_.

Comment: The linked article actually quotes from Pokemon GO Hub's article.

Comment: @Goodra I never claimed that you were wrong. I was just remarking that the list is shocking. What does that have to do with "as SE suggests"?

Comment: I've read that somewhere, SE is a placebo share research or something. If I recalled it correctly... @TheGreatDuck

Comment: @Goodra but what does that at all have to do with me being surprised that niantic bans caterpie from people abusing the system?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck , ikr! idek y I put that. Might have been an off day...

Comment: @Goodra fair enough. I thought maybe that you thought I was claiming your information to be incorrect or lies.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Nah don't worry

Answer (score 10):

So far, the [Pokemon Hub Website](https://pokemongohub.net/post/breaking-news/niantic-confirms-new-anti-bot-security-tool-activated/) has a list of Pokemon that cannot be seen:

- Evolved Pokemon
- Starters
- Caterpie
- Weedle
- Spearow
- Clefairy
- Vulpix
- Jigglypuff
- Venonat
- Mankey
- Growlithe
- Abra
- Slowpoke
- Gastly
- Onix
- Drowzee
- Voltorb
- Koffing
- Chansey
- Tangela
- Horsea
- Scyther
- Lapras
- Eevee
- Porygon
- Omanyte
- Kabuto
- Aerodactyl
- Snorlax
- Dratini
- Hoothoot
- Chinchou
- Mareep
- Sudowoodo
- Aipom
- Unown
- Girafarig
- Shuckle
- Sneasel
- Teddiursa
- Remoraid
- Stantler
- Larvitar

They also have a list of Pokemon that they believe are not visible to banned accounts, but aren't completely sure:

- Regionals
- Diglett
- Doduo
- Seel
- Grimer
- Shellder
- Exeggcute
- Cubone
- Hitmonlee
- Hitmonchan
- Lickitung
- Jynx
- Electabuzz
- Magmar
- Pinsir
- Yanma
- Wobbuffet
- Pineco
- Dunsparce
- Swinub
- Mantine
- Skarmory
- Houndour
- Phanpy
- Hitmontop
- Miltank

Lastly, there are two Pokemon they aren't sure about at all:

- Ponyta
- Rhyhorn

Comment: It is almost easier to list which are left...

Comment: @Mathias711 perhaps; it is a lot of Pokemon.

Comment: Counting this list is about 75 plus evolved pokemon.  I would estimate that the number of pokemon which are still visible is less than 75.  Might be an interesting list of what Niantic considers common.